# Russian speaking at the ending credits track from "Grand Budapest Hotel" (2014)

Tags: значения, other-languages

In this https://youtu.be/H22fZWySJ50?t=2m9s video, which I believe is a new arrangement of famous Russian folksong, someone speaks in Russian for 2 seconds. Can someone translate this saying to English please?

The speaking happens at 2:09 in the video.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "Раз, два, три, четыре!" which means "One, two, three, four!"

Comment: In fact it is very often used to add "russian flavor", for instance here's "russian version" of an English song by UOGB: [Leaning On A Lamp Post](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riS41Oh4MK8&t=1m2s) (it is heard on 1:13). There are some other cliches used during the song as well.

Answer (score 1):

Это инструментальный вариант (без слов) русской народной песни "Светит месяц, светит ясный". Фольклорная певица Надежда Бабкина произносит слова "Раз, два, три, четыре!"
This is the instrumental version (without words) russian folk song "The moon shines, it shines clear." Folk singer Nadezhda Babkina utters the words "One, two, three, four!"

Comment: This site is primarily aimed at non-native speakers, which the op apparently is. Please answer English questions in English. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a "one-two=three-four" count-off for the next segment of the performance.

Superb performance, BTW.